# My fresh installed ubuntu 12,4 won´t start without live usb drive

Tags: boot, live-usb

I just installed a fresh copy of ubuntu 12,04 in my netbook, through a live USB drive. I used the whole HDD and erased an existent win 7 partition. It installed everything and then asked me to reboot. When I did that, after rebooting, it only appeared the writer marker on top of a black screen and only that. Then, i plugged in again my usb drive and reboot. It loaded, but in the loading screen sent me (once) an error about the hard drive, that some file was missing (sorry i coulnd't write down the exact message). After that, I tried to re install ubuntu using my USB drive, but it sends me inmediately to the login screen. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you login with the pendrive inserted in the USB port, open a terminal and type this 
command

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda`. then
`sudo update-grub`.

Then reboot again to see what happens.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. However, just before you answered I was preparing a new USB drive, so I just made a fresh install again and everything worked fine. Thank you, again, for your time!